# can we use map function to extract subset of elements in string list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I extract a particular/desired line from a file:

```
contents = f.readlines()

//code..

contents[i+2].split()
```

This is the result:-

```
['Node', 'FC', 'NL', 'SSD', 'FC', 'NL', 'SSD', 'FC', 'NL', 'SSD']
```

Now I want only the last 3 entries:-

```
res = contents[i+2].split()
res1 = res[-3:]
['FC', 'NL', 'SSD']
```

Can I do this in one line using the map function?
Like this: If yes, I am not able to apply the logic

```
res = list(map(lambda L: L[-3:], contents[i+2].split())
```

Thanks for the help as always! I would like to have those lines reduced to 1 line.

Comment: No, you don't want to use map for this. Map applies a function to *each element*. You could use `filter` maybe, but don't do that. Just use string methods directly

Comment: Have you tried `res = contents[i+2].split()[-3:]` ?

Comment: If you must have it on one line, you can just do `contents[i+2].split()[-3:]`

Comment: I don't understand your thinking here. Why do you expect `map` to be useful here? Why do you want to try using `map`, and not something else?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga any other way.. to do those opetions in one line instead of 3 lines. Basically to fetch the line then split() and then extract last N elements  - in ONE single line?

Comment: @redpy Just use `res = contents[i+2].split()[-3:]`

Comment: sure thanks all.. I got the answer @iota  and everyone..! : )

Comment: I just showed you. But why do you care about the number of lines? Lines aren't a precious resource. You should strive to write code that is readable, maintainable, and not unnecessarily inefficient. Putting everything on one line is never good for anything except playing code golf

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the file has Values for these strings elements. The file is such that there are many rows of these and values for these. I want to extract only the last 3 of these "types" and the corresponding values for these which are in the file not shown here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res = contents[i+2].split()[-3:]
```